# Cannot correctly populate ListPicker control with Image and Name

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have created a ListPicker control for a user to change his or her background, but not all of the information is populated correctly in the ListPicker control. The problem arises when a user navigated to my SettingsPage, the text of all ListPicker items is displayed properly, but only the image of the currently selected background is shown. All other image backgrounds are blank. Furthermore, the weird thing is as I change the image backgrounds and navigate back and forth between the MainPage and the SettingsPage, every new image background that is selected will then show up in the ListPicker (along with all other previously selected backgrounds) while the backgrounds that haven't been selected do not have images shown in the ListPicker. So far what I have is as follows:

SettingsPage.xaml

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ThemeListPicker" Header="Theme" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                        SelectedIndex="{Binding}"
                                        SelectionChanged="ThemeListPicker_SelectionChanged">
                        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="50" Height="37.59" Margin="0,0,12,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

SettingsPage.xaml.cs

```
List<ThemeItem> themeList;

public SettingsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        themeList = new List<ThemeItem>()
        {
            new ThemeItem { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Themes/PanoramaBackground.png", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "Default" },

            new ThemeItem { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Themes/Abstract Pattern.jpg", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "Abstract Pattern" },
            new ThemeItem { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Themes/Asian Beauty.jpg", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "Asian Beauty" },
            new ThemeItem { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Themes/Autumn Leaf.jpg", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "Autumn Leaf" },                
            new ThemeItem { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Themes/Old Barn.png", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "Old Barn" }
        };

        ThemeListPicker.ItemsSource = themeList;
        ThemeListPicker.DataContext = ThemeListPicker.SelectedIndex;

    }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        //Respect the saved Theme index setting
        this.ThemeListPicker.SelectedIndex = Settings.ThemeIndex.Value;
    }

private void ThemeListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count <= 0) //to eliminate IndexOutOfRangeException
        {
            return;
        }

        //string selectedItem = e.AddedItems[0] as string;
        ThemeItem selectedItem = e.AddedItems[0] as ThemeItem;

        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            Settings.Theme.Value = selectedItem.Image.UriSource.ToString();
            Settings.ThemeIndex.Value = ThemeListPicker.SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
```

where ThemeItem is a small custom class

```
public class ThemeItem
{
    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How would I be able to properly load all Image backgrounds and respective text Names in the ListPicker control when the SettingsPage is navigatedTo?

EDIT: added Settings class info

```
public class Settings
{        
    //Theme settings
    public static readonly Setting<int> ThemeIndex = new Setting<int>("ThemeIndex", 0);

    //Theme Background
    public static readonly Setting<string> Theme = new Setting<string>("Theme", "Resources/Themes/PanoramaBackground.png");
    //public static readonly Setting<BitmapImage> Theme = new Setting<BitmapImage>("Theme", new Uri("/Resources/Themes/PanoramaBackground.png", UriKind.Relative));
}

//Encapsulates a key/value pair stored in Isolated Storage ApplicationSettings
public class Setting<T>
{
    string name;
    T value;
    T defaultValue;
    bool hasValue;

    public Setting(string name, T defaultValue)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            //Check for the cached value
            if (!this.hasValue)
            {
                //Try to get the value from Isolated Storage
                if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue(
                    this.name, out this.value))
                {
                    //It has not been set yet
                    this.value = this.defaultValue;
                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[this.name] = this.value;
                }
                this.hasValue = true;
            }
            return this.value;
        }
        set
        {
            //Save the value to Isolated Storage
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[this.name] = value;
            this.value = value;
            this.hasValue = true;
        }
    }

    public T DefaultValue
    {
        get { return this.defaultValue; }
    }

    //"Clear" cached value
    public void ForceRefresh()
    {
        this.hasValue = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's weird. I recreated the whole project using your code (copy pasted, except for the settings class which is not available, so I removed the two lines which use the class), and all the images are shown in the listpicker. all. i tried pngs, jpgs, different file names... still works. could you share the settings class for me (at least the important part), so I can test that too?

Comment: Still, everything works like it's supposed to when I added the settings class. All images are shown, for every item on the list. What is your build action for those images? What is the size of the images? I am throwing ideas, perhaps something will come up.

Comment: Thanks. Build action is resource, and most image sizes are around 1024x768, although the images are resized for the ListPicker to be 50*37.59 to keep roughly a 4:3 aspect ratio to mimic the actual size of the photo when used as a background.

Comment: I've noticed though that since I have about 100 items my ListPicker is loading into a new page, which is fine, although the image does not show up at all, only the text, although the text is not the name of the background but rather `ApplicationName.Views.ThemeItem`. Would it be better to just create a ListBox and populate that with the themes or maybe use a LongListSelector instead. And if so, what would be the best implementation (my list is loading very slow and the application lags)

Comment: Hah, this changes things. You didn't mention that you have more than five items so the listpicker opens the selector on a different page. OK, the reason for this is that you created a template for a simple item selector (up to five items, dropdown menu). In case of the longer list, you need to create a FullModeItemTemplate, too. Here is example of how to create FullModeItemTemplate: http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth Then you should get the pictures and the text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the FullModeItemTemplate so that the the ListPicker would populate correctly in another page.

SettingsPage.xaml

```
<Grid.Resources>

                        <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="50" Height="37.59" Margin="0,0,12,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="50" Height="37.59" Margin="0,0,12,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </Grid.Resources>

<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ThemeListPicker" Header="Theme" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                        FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}"
                                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}"
                                        SelectedIndex="{Binding}"
                                        SelectionChanged="ThemeListPicker_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you get the large list of items in the ListPicker, you need to create a template for it too. You only have the ItemTemplate at the moment. The property is called **FullModeItemTemplate** and the example of how to do that is shown here:

http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth

Comment: That definately worked! Although I still have the same issue with the images not populating correctly. Only the currently selected background shows up in the list, and all other images are blank, and then when a new background is selected its image will show up as well, but an item has to be selected first before the image will shwo up with its respective name.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot link?

Comment: I do not know how to do that, although I created a test project to test only the listpicker, and it worked with images except after about 20 ThemeItems populating the listpicker, I ran across a OutOfMemoryException. What would you recommend as to how the listpicker can be populated and used without this error? I've read around about virtualization but I have no idea how to do anything like that?

Comment: Are you still using smaller images (you mentioned 50x37.59)? 30 images of that size should NOT cause OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Well, when I first populate the list, I am loading the images from my directory, and they are very large to fit a panorama background, but when the user views the list the images are resized to 50x37.59. I may just have to bite the bullet and either not use images in my list or maybe just resize all the images for the ListPicker and then use the actual image size for the background.