# How to bind a button's normal and pressed background image?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, binding, windows-phone-8

I've managed to save the button style into my AppSetting class based on this code here [Cannot correctly populate ListPicker control with Image and Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480315/cannot-correctly-populate-listpicker-control-with-image-and-name)

Then I want to bind the button's normal and pressed background images (I've several button styles which the user can select in the settings page).

```
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>

                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>

                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">

                            <Grid>
                                <Image x:Name="NormalBackground" Source="{Binding ButtonUpSetting, Source={StaticResource AppSettings}}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                <Image x:Name="PressedBackground" Source="{Binding ButtonDownSetting, Source={StaticResource AppSettings}}" Stretch="Uniform"/>

                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In particular I would like to bind the following items to their respective uri sources but can't perform 'live' binding.

```
 <Image x:Name="NormalBackground" Source="{Binding ButtonUpSetting, Source={StaticResource AppSettings}}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
 <Image x:Name="PressedBackground" Source="{Binding ButtonDownSetting, Source={StaticResource AppSettings}}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

I've also implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`in my AppSetting class but the button style is not updated when I returned to the button page.

Update:

The button is only updated when I close and reopen the app. So it can read the values from the settings. But it isn't updated right after I change the setting.

The structure of the pages is like the following:

ButtonPage <> SettingPage <> AppSetting Class

So how do I make sure the ButtonPage "re-read" the settings in AppSetting class after I change them in the SettingPage? I am not sure the `INotifyPropertyChanged` notifies the ButtonPage because it's in the backstack while I make the changes on the SettingPage.

Setting the DataContext = AppSetting inside ButtonPage OnNavigatedTo  event does not make any different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out.

Only define the Datacontext in the code not in XAML so

```
<Image x:Name="NormalBackground" Source="{Binding ButtonUpSetting}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
<Image x:Name="PressedBackground" Source="{Binding ButtonDownSetting}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

Then

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        //Rebind all bindings to update button background images
        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            this.DataContext = null;
            this.DataContext = settings;
        }
        ....
```