# Image not shown in listpicker wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

i stuck in a problem. i want to bind an image and text data in listpicker wp7. but when i bind image and text into listpicker only text bind. image not bind.

here is my code:

```
public void loadvehicaltype()
        {
            List<vehical> listofvehical = new List<vehical>();

            listofvehical.Add(new vehical() { CarType= "Any Vehical"   });
            listofvehical.Add(new vehical() { CarType = "test1", carImage = "Images/car_Images/test_yellow.png" });
            listofvehical.Add(new vehical() { CarType = "test2"   });
            listofvehical.Add(new vehical() { CarType = "Any Vehical" });


            this.listPickerVehicalType.ItemsSource = listofvehical;
        }
```

and here is vehical class :

```
public class vehical
    {

        public string CarType { get; set; }
        public string carImage { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is XAML :

```
 <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listPickerVehicalType" Tap="listPickerVehicalType_Tap" SelectionMode="Single" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerItemTemplate}" FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate}"   FullModeHeader="Items" CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
```

and

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerItemTemplate">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CarType}" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
                <!--<Image Source="{Binding carImage}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Stretch="None" />-->

            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CarType}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding carImage}"  />
             </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
```

please help me to sort out this problem. i search this problem but no result found

Comment: 1) Can you just confirm that image is valid: set url to image available in internet (http://...) . 2) Set `Height` and `Width` of the `Image` control

Comment: @Ku6opr: thanks for your reply. what do you mean by "Url to image in internet" ? i set the Height and Width of image but same response

Comment: some public image url

Answer (score 0):

This is because your image has it's build action set to Resource (Which is the default). you switch it to Content:
right click on your image and set it's build action to Content

[Follow these link for more help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480315/cannot-correctly-populate-listpicker-control-with-image-and-name)

[Follow these link for more help](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth)